# Transform array of struct into array of strings to display as a table

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I was watching the following package: https://github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter

And I want to try to print my struct as something like that, but I couldn't covert my array of structs into the array of strings that the package needs.

So I tried something like that:

```
func print(quakes []Quake) {
    var data [][]string

    for _, quake := range quakes {
        b, err := json.Marshal(quake)
        append(data, []string(b))
    }

    table := tablewriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    table.SetHeader([]string{"Name", "Sign", "Rating"})

    for _, v := range newData {
        table.Append(v)
    }
    table.Render() // Send output
}
```

**My Quake Struct:**

```
type Quake struct {
    Googlemapref string `json:"googlemapref"`
    Segree       string `json: "degree"`
    DataUpdate   string `json: "dataUpdate"`
    MagType      string `json:"magType"`
    ObsRegion    string `json: "obsRegion"`
    Lon          string `json:"lon"`
    Source       string `json: "source"`
    Depth        int    `json:"depth"`
    TensorRef    string `json:"tensorRef"`
    Sensed       string `json:"sensed"`
    Shakemapid   string `json:"shakemapid"`
    Time         string `json:"time"`
    Lat          string `json:"lat"`
    Shakemapref  string `json:"shakemapref"`
    Local        string `json:"local"`
    Magnitud     string `json: "magnitud"`
}
```

Would appreciate some help since I am new in the laguage, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.  Firstly, the `append` function doesn't append in place so where you do `append(data, []string(b))` the result is thrown away so I think you want to do `data = append(data, []string(b))` instead.

Also, doing a `json.Marshal` on the struct will not make a slice of strings which you try to use it as.  Instead, it will produce a single string that has all of the values in such as `{"googlemapref":"something","depth":10}`.  The tablewriter you want to use expects to take a slice of values to put in the table that match the headings (where you appear to using the example headings of `"Name", "Sign", "Rating"`.

You *could* use the `reflect` package like `json` does to populate the fields in each row but I think this would be more complexity than it is worth and you are better just filling in each row by calling the relevant fields:

```
func print(quakes []Quake) {
    var data [][]string

    for _, quake := range quakes {
        row := []string{quake.Googlemapref, quake.Segree, strconv.Itoa(quake.Depth),...}
        data = append(data, row)
    }

    table := tablewriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    table.SetHeader([]string{"googlemapref", "degree", "depth",...})

    for _, v := range newData {
        table.Append(v)
    }
    table.Render() // Send output
}
```

(I've left the `...` for you to fill in the other fields yourself but included depth to show how to convert it to a string).